# multiple selection in uitableview - dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is causing issue

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

```
//selected rows is mutablearray
if (aCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
  [selectedRows addObject:indexPath];
 }
```

Problem here is when I scroll uitableview, all selection is messed up. What is the best way keep track of selected cells? I also do not want to use checkmark I just want to change background color of selected rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the selected color of the selected cell.`cell.selectedcolor = [uicolor blackcolcor];`
or you can use this method for change background color of the custom tableeview cell

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
[bgColorView release];
```

Comment: problem im facing is when i scroll tableview..as cells are rendered again..color selected for say row 10 is also there on row 20..

Comment: @Akki why u put the checkmark accesory for tableview cell if its not needed?use default tableview cell code for rowatindexpath and put my code into it for changing the selected color change.

Comment: Ok...but I also want multiselect to be possible..any suggestion?

Comment: @Akki -(UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleMultiSelect;
}
OR CLUCK THIS LINK FOR SAMPLE APP:https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master/VSCheckFavorites

Comment: @Akki ok o problem,if u fifnd the answer right please accept this.

Comment: still problem for me is on scrolling uitableview dequecellwith reusableidentifier